# Speeding up loading raster

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, mapserver, mosaic

I georeference a tif image and then I clipped that image in a mosaic.

I did a index of these images but when I load them is very slow(7 seconds or more to display the first tile). How can I do to go faster?

I tried many ideas from the mapserver document but I does't work. Any idea?

Comment: From the Mapserver side, could you attach the gdalinfo report of your tiff file and the LAYER section of the mapfile?

Comment: Do you mean the ms_error file? 
[Mon Aug 04 09:58:55 2014].847000 msResampleGDALToMap in effect: cellsize = 309.717113
[Mon Aug 04 09:58:55 2014].847000 msDrawGDAL(ortofoto): using RAW_WINDOW=41 56 215 200, dst=0,0,22,20
[Mon Aug 04 09:58:55 2014].847000 msDrawRasterLayerGDAL(): red,green,blue,alpha bands = 1,2,3,0
[Mon Aug 04 09:58:55 2014].880000 msResampleGDALToMap in effect: cellsize = 312.044146

Comment: No, I mean the report which is generated with this tool http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html

Comment: GTiff/GeoTIFF Size is 256, 256 Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N", GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0]

Comment: UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]
GeoTransform = 91500.18056444808, 31.69171347581339, -0.1308510605117187 552236.570192243, -0.06342412711890534, -31.70726921305248 Metadata: AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata: INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   91500.181,  552236.570) (  5d19' 3.29"E,  4d59' 8.88"N)
Lower Left  (   91466.683,  544119.509) (  5d19' 3.67"E,  4d54'45.06"N)
Upper Right (   99613.259,  552220.334) (  5d23'26.23"E,  4d59' 9.81"N)

Comment: Do you mean that you have clipped your good big geotiff file into 256x256 pixel sized tiles and then made a mosaic from tiles on the server side and finally you use that mosaic as an input for Mapserver?

Comment: I think so. And it's very slow

Comment: The right way to go is to use the big image as a single tiff but make sure it has an inner tiling and in addition to create overviews with gdaladdo utility. Read slides 10-13 from http://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-on-steroids and the first commands from this thread for example this http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Converting-ecw-to-tif-for-Geoserver-td5033205.html. They deal with Geoserver but the essentials are the same for Mapserver: inner tiling, suitable compression if disk space matters, and having overviews. You will find more examples from the web.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. I can't click on the answer because it was a comment.

Comment: I copied that comment into an answer because I think that it makes it easier for other people to find the advice later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Read also the comments below the question because they are more valuable than this answer alone.*

The right way to go is to use the big image as a single internally tiled tiff file and to create overviews with gdaladdo utility. Read slides 10-13 from http://slideshare.net/geosolutions/geoserver-on-steroids and study the first commands from this thread http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Converting-ecw-to-tif-for-Geoserver-td5033205.html. They both deal with Geoserver but the essentials are the same for Mapserver: use internal tiling in tiff files and also a suitable compression method if disk space matters, and don't forget to create overviews.